# Is it normal that Android keeps killing my background service for no reason

Tags: android

My sticky back ground service is killed every 20-40 minutes by the OS and that is not caused by exceptions or errors from my app according to logcat. I did some research about this, most of them say that the os kills services when memory is low. However, this is not my case. My service only consumes a few MB memory and my device just got a factory reset so there is plenty of memory space left. 

My service is normally killed and schedule to restart along with a few other system services. In the log it says my service is scheduled to restart after a few hundreds of ms. The timer in the setting -> running apps for my service is not reset to 0 no matter how many times my service restarts.

I have a few KB of critical data in a static hashmap, will they still be there after restart? If not,what can I do to save my temporary data in this circumstance? will the os give me time to save them to files and where should I make the call?

Comment: Have you installed any battery saver or data saver ..It will kill all the background services and reschedule it ...and also see the battery saver profile might be active..

Comment: @KIKIJ You can use shared preferences for storing your data

Comment: static variable is not reliable at all, try sharedpreference or save them into database.

Comment: @ali786 no, that is my only app after I factory reset my test device

Comment: @JaiSoni the data is constantly changing I need to do put and remove operation frequently. reading and saving it to a file each time I need to access it might be less efficient.

Comment: @KIKIJ , Try the shutapp application from android store it is good for listing background applications

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cant control when the OS will kill your service for making memory,You can start the service again from the app if the service is not running every certain time.
You can declare a static boolean reference in the service class and mark it as "true" in onCreate() and "false" in on onTaskRemoved() and onDestroy().
And then execute your functionality inside the if block ... 
if(boolean){
}

By doing this even if there two or more services(instance of same service) running at some point the code will be executed only by one service.